# create registration with slim and eloquent

Tags: eloquent, slim

Controller register method:

```
public function register($request, $response)
{       
$user = User::create([
    'username'=> $request->getParsedBody()['username'],
    'password'=> $request->getParsedBody()['password'],
    'nama'=> $request->getParsedBody()['nama'],
    'no_hp'=> $request->getParsedBody()['no_hp'],
    ]);

return $response->withJson([
    'succes' =>true , 
    'message'=>'Pendaftaran Berhasil',
    'data'   => $user
    ]);
}
```

User model code:

```
<?php
namespace App\models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model 
{
    public   $timestamps  = false;
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'password', 'nama', 'no_hp'];
    protected $table    = "users";
}
```

how can I check if username is already exist in database?

I use slim and eloquent

Comment: `User::where('username', $username)->count() == 0`?

Comment: which part i need to change with that code bro ?

Comment: Before creating your User model, check **if** the count of users with the same username == 0. If so, create the user model. If not, throw an error. You may want to do this with a custom validator rule if you're using some kind of validation library, but that's up to you. SO isn't exactly a code writing service.

Comment: thanks a lot man , its work ,u are my saviour

Comment: No problem. Let me write an answer real quick so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent allows you to run `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries using the `->count()` method on its query builder. To verify that there are no users with the same username, you could use something like:

```
if (User::where('username', $username)->count() == 0) {
    // register the new user
} else {
    // throw an error
}
```